# How to efficiently move big data from a data center to Azure Blob Storage for later processing via HDInsight?

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

I need to setup scheduled tasks which purpose is to copy/move large amounts of data from an on-premises data center to Windows Azure Blob Storage.

The options I've explored are WebHDFS and Flume (the latter does not seem to be supported by HDInsight currently).

What is the most efficient way to transfer unstructured files from a data center to Windows Azure Blob Storage?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HDInsight, you don't need to involve HDFS at all. In fact you don't need your cluster to be running to upload the data. The best way of getting data into HDInsight is to upload it to Azure Blob Storage, using either the standard .NET clients, or something third-party like Azure Management Studio or AzCopy.

If you want to stream the data constantly, then you are probably better setting up something like Flume, Kafka or Storm to work against an HDInsight cluster, but that will require a certain amount of customisation on the cluster itself, which means you'll run into problems with reboots, and require a permanent cluster.

Comment: Storm is now part of General Availability in Azure, and does not require customization on the cluster for base implementations.

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/02/20/microsoft-makes-apache-storm-generally-available-and-improves-productivity-for-real-time-analytics-on-big-data/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention how much data you're talking about (you just said *large amounts*). But... assuming it's 100's of TB or petabytes, Azure has an [Import/Export Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-import-export-service/) which offers disk-ship.

Outside of that, you'd need to use your own code or use a 3rd-party tool such as Microsoft's [AzCopy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/04/01/azcopy-using-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx) to transfer your content to blobs. Remember that you'll be able to perform parallel uploads, to compress time (as long as your data center's bandwidth is large enough for you to see the benefits).

Answer (score 0):

You could use CloudBerry drive and Flume to stream data to HDInsight cluster/Azure Blob storage

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2014/03/18/using-apache-flume-with-hdinsight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No,you cannot use flume to stream data directly to HDInsight. post from Microsoft blog says that

> a vast majority of Flume consumers will land their streaming data into HDFS – and HDFS is not the default file system used with HDInsight. Even if it were - we do not expose public facing Name Node or HDFS endpoints so the Flume agent would have a terrible time reaching the cluster! So, for these reasons and a few others , the answer is typically "no. …it won't work or its not supported"

source :http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2014/03/18/using-apache-flume-with-hdinsight.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Answer (score -2):

It also is worth mentioning the ExpressRoute option. Microsoft now has a program called ExpressRoute where your datacenter can be connected straight to Azure with a much faster connection, in cooperation with your ISP. See also http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/expressroute/